# try to delete String from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

i try to delete phoneNumber from database but it is not working. How can i delete phoneNumber 
from database. I searched previous post but i find same solution the code is here. but not working

// delete a particular number

```
public boolean deleteNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_PHONENUMBER + "=" + phoneNumber, null) > 0;
}
```

// list view code is here

// display number in ListView
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfPhoneNumber));

```
listView.setLongClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    // On Long Click Listener  
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewNumber.this,listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        numberToDelete = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // PopUp Menu
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(ViewNumber.this, view);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu_viewnumber, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {


            @Override
              public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewNumber.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // deleting number from database
                    db.open();
                    boolean check = db.deleteNumber(numberToDelete);
                    db.close();

                    if(check == true)
                    {
                        Log.d("NUMBER del from db", numberToDelete);
                    }

                    Log.d("numberToDelete", "" +numberToDelete);
                }

                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.edit) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewNumber.this, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                 return false;
              }
            });

        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have some error or the number just keep appearing on your database?

Comment: code seems correct. Are you sure that number is not being deleted from SQLite database?

Comment: i am not getting any error. string just not delete

Comment: not deleted from database or from some view such as list or textview?

Comment: db transaction - if such - is ended too, right?

Comment: from both listview and from database. `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean deleteNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    if(db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_PHONENUMBER + "=?", new String[] {phoneNumber})>0){
      return true;
    }else{
     return false;
    }
}
```

more info   [**SQLiteDatabase Delete**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

***public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
Added in API level 1
Convenience method for deleting rows in the database.***

> **Parameters**
>
> *table*   the table to delete from
>
> *whereClause* the optional WHERE clause to apply when deleting. Passing null will delete all rows.
>
> *whereArgs* You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs.  The values will be bound as
>   Strings.
>
> **Returns** the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the
>   whereClause.