# getting error when insert data in sqlite in android Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 19 rows, 2 columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting following error when insert data in `sqlite`. I searched all previous post i think code right. When first executed then worked correctly. but not working

```
 01-28 11:56:51.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11292): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

// programmer code here

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

db.open();

String allNumberText = "";

            Cursor cursor = db.getAllNumber();

            Log.d("First", "First");

            if( cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                Log.d("Run here", "Run here");
                do{
                    Log.d("Second", "Second");


                    allNumberText += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONENUMBER));


                    Log.d("Third", "Third");
                    //allNumberText += " ";
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();

            displayNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayNumber);
            displayNumber.setText(allNumberText);
```

// DBApter code is here

public class DBAdapter {

```
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_ID";
static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "phoneNumber";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PhoneNumberDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tableOfPhoneNumber";
static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS DATABASE_NAME ");
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

// open database
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// close database
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

// insert phone number in database
public long insertPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// delete a particular number
public boolean deleteNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_PHONENUMBER + "=" + phoneNumber, null) > 0;
}

/*
public boolean deleteNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_PHONENUMBER + " = ?", new String[] {phoneNumber}) > 0;
}
*/

// retrieves all the number
public Cursor getAllNumber()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_PHONENUMBER}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// retrieves a particular number
public Cursor getNumber(String phoneNumber) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_PHONENUMBER} , KEY_PHONENUMBER + "=" +phoneNumber, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(mCursor != null)
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like KEY_PHONENUMBER column is not there. Check your DB's tables. May be you have missed that column in your create query.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: and please post your table creation statement

Comment: I posted table creation class

Comment: you are running on device or emulator ?

Comment: i am running on device karbann A9+

Comment: remove the application from the device and then run it again

Comment: Hi @Amrola i have also another problem to delete String from database. could go through that link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387578/try-to-delete-string-from-sqlite-database?answertab=oldest#tab-top) your help i will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the application from the device and then run it again , because the database is created in the first time you run the application and if you edit your tables , it will not take the update until you craete the database again , so remove the application and run it again , this will create the database again .

then try to do something like the following :

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();

String allNumberText = "";

            Cursor cursor = db.getAllNumber();

while(cursor.moveToNext()){

allNumberText += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONENUMBER))+"  ";

}
cursor.close();

db.close();
```

and give me some feedback .

Hope that helps .

Comment: removing the application from the device. Worked for me. Thank you